# unexpected symbol 'public' while creating float

Tags: c#, error-handling, symbols

I am new to unity but I have an error that appears whenever I create a variable.

It says error cs1525: unexpected symbol 'public'

here is my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        public float speed = 3.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `public` is for class members. There's no need to put it in a local variable declaration, and it's not legal there in any case. Decide whether you want `speed` to be a class field or a local variable, and declare it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Class members should be defined inside the class block, but outside the methods.

Move all your "public" lines above the "void Start()" line.

Answer (score 0):

As Flux and Peter mentioned, access modifiers like public and private can only be applied to **Class level members**. This means members that are at the same level as your functions.

Depending on whether you want to use the speed variable everywhere in this class or just in one function, will dictate what approach you use.

Now based on my experience in game programming, speed is something you would want as a class level variable, and you would want to be able to access that variable from other objects as well.

So I will also point out that you **should** use encapsulation for a very good reason.  If at some point you want to change how the speed variable is used, or how it is calculated, then encapsulation will allow you to change the implementation of that "property" without necessarily having to modify the code in other objects that use it.

e.g.

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 3.0f;

    public void SetSpeed(float newSpeed)
    {
        speed = newSpeed;
    }

    public float GetSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        ...
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```